# SQL add wild characters to LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, character, sql-like

MYSQL:

```
SELECT CASE_ID
FROM `CASE`
WHERE CASE_ID LIKE
    (SELECT EMP_ID
     FROM CASE_EMPLOYER_REL
     WHERE CASE_ID = 100)
  AND IS_EMPLOYER = 'Y'
```

How do I add wild characters to LIKE - % _ etc.

Comment: you would have googled or went through the mysql tutorials before asking the question here

Answer (score 0):

With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:

1. % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
2. _ matches exactly one character.

   mysql> SELECT 'David!' LIKE 'David_';
           -> 1
   mysql> SELECT 'David!' LIKE '%D%v%';
           -> 1

To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by the escape character. If you do not specify the ESCAPE character, “\” is assumed.

1. **\% matches one “%” character.**
2. **_ matches one “_” character.**

   `mysql> SELECT 'David!' LIKE 'David\_';
           -> 0
   mysql> SELECT 'David_' LIKE 'David\_';
           -> 1`

for more information about `LIKE`and `WILDCARD` [OFFICIAL LINK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CONCAT` in the subquery select list.

```
select case_id 
from case 
where 
    case_id like (select CONCAT(emp_id, '%') from case_employer_rel where case_id = 100) 
    and is_employer = 'Y'
```